# columns IsShow, IsEnabled, IsClose, XType don't exist in the table

Tags: sql-server

Can someone please explain to me the use of AS keyword in this query and the fields?

```
select distinct 1, rg.GroupName as DisplayName, rg.GroupName as GroupName, 
null as IsShow, 
null as  [IsEnable],
null as [IsClose],
0 as XType,
null as ID
from dbo.m_Roles rg
```

Comment: Google "SQL-Server Alias"

Comment: @DVT did not find anything. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select 1 as 'one', 2 two, 3 [and three]
```

A column does not necessarily need to be in any table to be added to a result set.

AS is implicit for [column alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx), squared brackets and quotes are for avoiding error when aliases have a blank space in its name.

Answer (score 1):

`As` in this case is a column alias. So the result set will use the column names after the `AS`

Comment: The columns IsShow, IsEnabled, IsClose, XType don't exist in the table m.Roles.. They are created at runtime. I am not really clear how this happens

Comment: @neo try this `Select 1 as 'one', 2 two, 3 [and three]`. The column does not need to exists in any table to be added to a resultset. AS is implicit for column alias,  squared brackets and quotes are for avoiding error when aliases have a black space in its name

Comment: @horaciux thanks. definitely, helps my understainding.

Comment: @neo. I'm glad it helps. Edit your question, add your first comment in it.`he columns IsShow, IsEnabled, IsClose, XType don't exist in the table`